# Orchard CMS ask for an invite token to link to backend data during registration using workflows only

Tags: orchardcms

I am using Orchard CMS v1.9 and want to display a custom registration page to accept the usual username/password/email and an additional token (invite token). The token will be used to match the user to some to custom data on the server.

I have walked through this blog [Customizing User Registation With Dynamic Forms And Workflows](http://www.ideliverable.com/blog/customizing-user-registration-and-login-with-dynamic-forms-and-workflows).  But in addition to what is achieved in this blog I want to force a registering user to enter a token.  The token is used to lookup data on the server and create a link to the userpart.

Adding the token to the form is not the issue - its the querying and linking the entered token to the backend data and storing it in the userpart that im finding awkward.

- Is this possible using just workflows - or do i need a custom module?  I did not see a custom action that allowed me to match the token and link.
- Is there a custom module already available that does something
  similar?

Comment: We have a similar system in place (but more complex with custom users). However, I think in your scenario the easiest way would be to store the inviteToken in a custom record and link that to a user.

You may also want to build a custom MvcController that handles the link. Look at how the two-factor-auth is done in the Orchard.Users module for this.

I can post a more detailed answer if you're interested in this approach.

Comment: Id appreciate if you could elaborate how you achieved a solution.  My needs are actualy more complex, I simplified the scenario for the question.

Comment: Alright, I just started to write an answer but I will invest some more time and strip out as much code as possible to make it more clear. Hang in there, this will take some time ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: This approach is currently based on Orchard 1.10 but was initially developed on the 1.9.x branch. It does not rely on Dynamic Forms and Workflows, but I think you could achieve something similar with those modules.*

Okay so I ended up building an example module with our approach to extended users / activation system. I stripped out a lot of code, but also let some juicy parts, which aren't directly related to your answer, in it.

First you should check out the [UsersController](https://github.com/Xceno/Xceno.CustomUsers/blob/master/Controllers/UsersController.cs#L39) it has the activate actions you are searching for. You may need to extend the orchard LogOn-View and include some GET & POST Actions accordingly.

```cs
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Activate(string activationCode)
{
    // validation stuff....

    var viewModel = new CustomUserActivate
    {
        // This is the activationCode you're looking for
        ActivationCode = userFromActivationCode.ActivationCode,
        UserName = userFromActivationCode.User.UserName,
        WelcomeText = userFromActivationCode.WelcomeText,
        Email = userFromActivationCode.User.Email
    };

    return this.View(viewModel);
}

[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Activate(CustomUserActivate input)
{
    if ( input == null )
    {
        this.ModelState.AddModelError("_form", this.T("The argument cannot be null").Text);
    }

    CustomUserPart customUserPart = null;
    if ( this.ModelState.IsValid )
    {
        customUserPart = this.myService.GetCustomUserByActivationCode(input.ActivationCode);

        if ( customUserPart == null || customUserPart.User == null || customUserPart.User.UserName != input.UserName )
        {
            this.notifier.Add(NotifyType.Error, this.T("The activation failed"));
        }

        if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(input.Email) )
        {
            this.ModelState.AddModelError("Email", this.T("You must specify an email address.").Text);
        }
        else if ( input.Email.Length >= 255 )
        {
            this.ModelState.AddModelError("Email", this.T("The email address you provided is too long.").Text);
        }
        else if ( !Regex.IsMatch(input.Email, UserPart.EmailPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) )
        {
            // http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx    
            this.ModelState.AddModelError("Email", this.T("You must specify a valid email address.").Text);
        }
        else if ( !this.myService.VerifyEmailUnicity(customUserPart.User.Id, input.Email) )
        {
            this.ModelState.AddModelError("Email", this.T("This email address is already in use.").Text);
        }
    }

    if ( !this.ModelState.IsValid )
    {
        return this.View(input);
    }

    Debug.Assert(customUserPart != null, "customUserPart != null");
    var user = customUserPart.User;
    var userParams = new CreateUserParams(user.UserName, input.Password, input.Email, passwordQuestion: null, passwordAnswer: null, isApproved: true);
    this.myService.ActivateCustomUser(customUserPart.Id, userParams);

    this.notifier.Add(NotifyType.Information, this.T("Your account was activated. You can now log in."));
    return this.RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Account", new { area = "Orchard.Users" });
}
```

The interesting stuff happens in [MyService.cs](https://github.com/Xceno/Xceno.CustomUsers/blob/master/Services/MyService.cs).
We designed the activation system so that you can still leverage all the features of the Orchard.User Module like Email-Verifcation.
For this we've implemented some [CustomSettings](https://github.com/Xceno/Xceno.CustomUsers/blob/master/Models/CustomSettingsPart.cs), where you can decide if your user get's completely activated when an ActivationCode is used or if you trigger the normal Orchard mechanism.

I guess it's best to checkout the module and step through the code in Visual Studio.

Here a two screenshots of our activation views.

**Step 1 - Enter your activation code**
[image]

**Step 2 - Fill in the remaining fields**
[image]

**Profit!**

All the additional source is to make use of the CustomUser / ActivationCode in Workflows, Events, Tokens, etc. But I leave this for you to discover.

If you want more detailed descriptions of the source on GitHub let me know.
Hope this helps!